# How to filter if a directory is root directory in windows/qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I am showing contents of folder (only show certain files) when user is typing path. I don't want to show content if its a root folder (c:\ drive) because it searches all sub directories and it would take too long and is not needed.

The problem is if I type "c:\\" in the edit box, it still searches the C:\ drive but QDir::isRoot() doesn't pick it up. How can I catch path accurately that could be root path or even program files path? I am using Windows 7.

```
void MainWindow::on_lineEditSourceFolder_textChanged(const QString &arg1)
{
    //qDebug() << "edit text changed: " << arg1;
    QDir dir( arg1 ) ;

    if ( !dir.exists() )
    {
        model->clear();
        return;
    }

    QString dirPath = dir.absolutePath();

   if (dir.isRoot() )
   {
       qDebug() << arg1 << " is root";
       return;
   }

    searchFiles( dirPath );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in QT. Have a look at the source of `QDir.isRoot()` to be sure, then submit a bug report.

But the QT [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdir.html#isRoot) might show a workaround. Try changing this:

```
QString dirPath = dir.absolutePath();
```

into

```
QString dirPath = dir.canonicalPath();
```

Comment: PS: Neither have windows nor QT installed on my box, so cannot check myself.

Answer (score 0):

Here's `isRoot()` behavior:

1. returns false on `c`
2. returns false on `c:`
3. returns true on `c:\`

So when you enter `c:`, `isRoot()` returns false and `searchFiles()` will be called. When you subsequently press `\`, `isRoot()` returns `true`, but you did not call `model->clear()` before returning. This gives the impression that `c:\` still call `searchFiles()`.

So you should do a clear before returning:

```
if (dir.isRoot() )
{
  qDebug() << arg1 << " is root";
  model->clear();
  return;
}
```

If you don't want `c:` to search files too, append a `\` to the directory before checking for root:

```
void MainWindow::on_lineEditSourceFolder_textChanged(const QString &arg1)
{
  QString temp = arg1 + '\\';
  QDir dir( temp ) ;
  ....
```